# How to include a text file as part of a built Netbeans project

Tags: netbeans, text-files, filenotfoundexception

This is my first post on the forum, so I hope I am following the correct procedure with this question.

I have lately been struggling with a program, in which a text file is used to read in data. In Netbeans the program works perfectly, but as soon as I Clean and Build the project, a FileNotFoundException error is encountered.

Although this is not my actual program, I have made a rough example of a similar concept below:

```
    package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test
{

    private Scanner scanFile;

    public void update()
    {
         try
        {
             scanFile = new Scanner(new File("Textfiles\\text.txt"));

             while (scanFile.hasNextLine())
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scanFile.next());
             }

        }
        catch(Exception i)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test().update();
    }

}
```

In the above example, when run in Netbeans, an output box with the data in the text file is shown. When I clean and build the project, and try and run the .jar file that is created, the following error is returned: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Textfiles/text.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Does anyone have any advice as to how I could solve this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try to stream the text file content instead. Make sure your text file is in the same directory as the 'Test' class.

Example:

```
Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));

while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scanFile.next());
}
```